# Background AlertDialog stay white when i'm in night mode

Tags: android, background, android-alertdialog

I'm using `@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog` for my alert dialog and the background stay white 
when i switch to the night mode. Is this the expected behavior ?

I can solve this problem by overriding android:background.. but i don't know if it's good.

Comment: what Android Versions are you targeting? Is that the same for all or only on specific devices/versions?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I target Android 10